# How to implement "make install" in a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, gnu-make

So here's the repo I'm working with: https://github.com/Garuda1/unixlib

I'd like to know where my compiled lib (`unixlib.a`) and where my header (`unixlib.h`) should be so as to be able to use the lib (under Linux-x86 or Linux-x86_64) simply by compiling with:

```
$ gcc my_source.c -lunixlib
```

and including the header in `my_source.c`.

I suppose I add do this to `Makefile`:

```
install:
    mv $(NAME).a $(LIB_PATH)
    mv unixlib.h $(HEADER_PATH)
```

but I don't know what `$(LIB_PATH)` and `$(HEADER_PATH)` are...

Comment: Why `mv`? This removes the header file from your source directory. `cp` or `install` are usually used here. The target paths are usually something like `$(prefix)/lib` and `$(prefix)/include`; where do you want to install your files?

Comment: I want to install them where they need to go, basically if I create `foo.c`, in which I `#include <unixlib.h>`, I want to be able to compile it with `gcc  -lunixlib foo.c`

Comment: "Where they need to go" is distro/flavor dependent and in your case on the default Include/Lib pathes for gcc. You should go for `/usr/local` as *prefix*, meaning `LIB_PATH=$(prefix)/lib` and `HEADER_PATH=$(prefix)/include` like Karsten Koop wrote with `prefix=/usr/local`. `/usr/` is in general managed by the distros package manager and `/usr/local` commonly used for "local installations" - [you can read about that in the FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). Builders can override it using `make install prefix=/home/example`

Comment: @Garuda1 The point Karsten is making is you should use *`install`* so that you can not only specify the permission modes but it's also self-documentary (if you want to go for that). At the very least use *`cp`*! - *`mv`* is simply wrong.

Answer (score 35):

Normally in UNIX systems the headers go to `$PREFIX/include`, library files go to `$PREFIX/lib`, where `PREFIX` can be `/usr` or `/usr/local` or whatever. In linux, if you install your library to these directories it will be found by `gcc` as you want with just `gcc my_source.c -lunixlib`.

The `PREFIX` environment variable is commonly used by various build tools to supply that prefix.

I would also recommend to use `DESTDIR` variable, it is used by Debian packaging tools at least.

So, the makefile would be like:

```
# PREFIX is environment variable, but if it is not set, then set default value
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
    PREFIX := /usr/local
endif

install: unixlib.a
    install -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install -m 644 unixlib.a $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/include/
    install -m 644 unixlib.h $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/include/
```

Note, the `install -d ...` is used just in case if directory does not exist in the supplied `DESTDIR` for example.

You can also have a look at my non-recursive template for `make` to find some hints: https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/blob/master/src/prorab.mk

Comment: And to add: man pages go in *`/usr/local/share/man`* (though there are additional subdirectories there that are for the sections of the man page...should you wish to go that way - the system counterpart would be with the prefix being *`/usr`*). And also similar is *`/usr/src`*. While I'm at it I'll add that for 64-bit libraries it should be *`/usr/lib64`*.

Comment: The thing I don't like about "install" is it is just a glorified "cp".  It always does it, even if unnecessary. That is it still installed, even if the installed file is newer, or even the same file (md5sum).  Scripts for example that are running may go 'weird' if overwritten when unnecessary.  Is there a smarter way for make files to install just the changes and updates?

Comment: You can also use `install -D …`, which will automatically create any directories as needed when copying SOURCE to DEST. https://linux.die.net/man/1/install

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia it depends on which `install` utility you have, `GNU` one or `BSD`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Install_(Unix)